# ASP.Net page load updating Update Panel

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to AJAX and wondered if i'm approaching things in the right way.

The page i'm building is literally just a progress page. i.e a process gets invoked from the page load and I add a message to the page to show the result, then another process runs and I add a new message for the result of that process etc, up to 10 processes can run sequentially and there is no user interaction. I didn't want the screen to flicker after each update message so I thought of Ajax

The way i've achieved this seems odd.....

- Setup `UpdatePanel` with a hidden button in it
- Create a `ClientScriptManager` on Code Behind Page Load to invoke a Javascript function (1st time in)
- 'Click' the button in the Javascript function
- Do the 1st Process on the C# code behind in the `Button_Click` method
- Use the `ClientScriptManager` in the c# to `Invoke` the Javascript to click the button again
- Do the next Process on the C# code behind in the `Button_Click` method

I'd rather just start the processes on the C# page load and update the `UpdatePanel` without it flashing.!

*****Here is my latest code using your recommendations with the Sleep Thread emulating the processes which will be taking place, however it's not updating in real time....i.e Recalculating Quotation and Storing Data appear after both instructions have completed.

```
            Literal literal1 = new Literal();
            literal1.Text = "Recalculating Quotation <br/>";
            literal1.ID = "Message1";
            updpnlSubmit.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literal1);
            updpnlSubmit.Update();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            Literal literal2 = new Literal();
            literal2.Text = "Storing Data<br/>";
            literal2.ID = "Message2";
            updpnlSubmit.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(literal2);
            updpnlSubmit.Update();
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Damien, just whether i'm getting the point....I mean it works but does it raise eyebrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drop an update panel onto the page & set its Update mode to
   conditional
2. Inside the update panel, place a label/literal control for your processing message
3. Inside pageLoad event execute each process & display a status message then update your updatePanel from codebehind like
4. Drop an UpdateProgress to show a progress image while processing

   ```
    if (Process1())
     lblStatus.Text = " Process 1 completed.;
    UpdatePanel1.Update();

    // Do this for Process 2

    // Do this for Process 3 etc.
   ```

Only problem I have is that what if process 2 is depedant on Process 1 & it fails ? You have to manage the rollback yourself. Again, this is just raw but you get the idea.

Comment: I'm looking for the progress messages to be real time....if I put the processing in the page load doesn't the page load have to complete before the screen is displayed? Sorry if i'm missing the point....

Comment: Yes they will be real time however it depends upon your requirement. you can also try 'LoadComplete' event if you need to specifically load the controls first. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events

Comment: Damien thanks for your help so far i'm using your bits to make progress...here is my code now on the postback from the page

Comment: Right have got rid of the client script manager on my pageload (no need for it) and used the UpdatePanel page load to fire my processes (nice one Damien) just need to get the messages firing in real time now....code added to the description up top...also how do i rate your responses they have been really helpful so far..

Comment: You can click the up arrow to vote my answer. Also if you solve your problem you can mark it as answer. Anyway, looking at your code, don't use sleep in production. Use a timer control instead if it fits you. Also in your code, don't add a new literal everytime, just set the Text property on every update.